# Returning the index of a String parameter in an array

Tags: java

While I know that this code should work to return the index, for some reason it's skipping the if statement and going straight to the else, when I know that the name is within the array, with the array that I'm using for testing. Won't even print the "if - reading" line.

```
public int find(String name)
{
    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.shoppingItems.length;i++)
    {
        if(this.shoppingItems[i].equals(name))
        {
            System.out.println("If - Reading");
            index = i;
        }
        else
        {
            index = -1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(index);

    return index;
}

//Main

  ShoppingItem[] items = new ShoppingItem[]{new ShoppingItem("Eggs",3.2),new ShoppingItem("Bread",2.8),new ShoppingItem("Bacon",9),new ShoppingItem("Peas",2),new ShoppingItem("Spinach",4),new ShoppingItem("Chocolate",8)};

ShoppingList itemList = new ShoppingList(items);

itemList.find("Bread");
```

Comment: Hint, try to use this method to search for *last* element in array. Also what is the content of `shoppingItems`? Does it store Strings or ShoppingList?

Comment: Looks like you are comparing a `ShoppingItem` to a `String` here : `if(this.shoppingItems[i].equals(name))`. Maybe you need somehing like `if(this.shoppingItems[i].getName().equals(name))`

Comment: `shoppingItems` isn't defined in the posted code.

Comment: Set `int index = -1`. Remove the `else-statement`. Put a `break;` after `index = 1`. I think this should work.

Comment: Aight, using getName() and removing the else statement seems to have worked, thanks for the help, this is the first time I've posted, so, sorry if it was vague, amazed at how quick posts get responded

Answer (score 1):

*"While I know that this code should work to return the index, for some reason it's skipping the if statement and going straight to the else"*

Stop! Java is not wrong; your code is, and it *shouldn't* work. Your `if` statement is not being skipped; it's just that the condition is always false, because `this.shoppingItems[i]` is a `ShoppingItem` object, and you are comparing it with `name`, which is a string. A `ShoppingItem` object is never equal to a string.

Presumably, what you want to test is whether the `ShoppingItem` object's **name** is equal to that string. Presumably, your class has a `getName` method, so you should test:

```java
if(this.shoppingItems[i].getName().equals(name)) {
    // ...
}
```

This is [a common kind of programming error](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/08993408.2014.952500), perhaps because [it's often acceptable in natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) to say one thing when you mean something closely related; e.g. you might say *"I asked the help desk"* when really you asked a *person* at the help desk, you did not ask the desk itself. This is a bit like that; you want the *item's name* to equal `name`, not the item itself.

Comment: I wasn't trying to say Java was wrong, was worded poorly, I should have just said I don't understand why it's skipping the if statement. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are compelled to use arrays, you can make things much easier by using lists.  They have quite a few useful features.

```java
      List<String> items = List.of("bread", "juice", "eggs", "milk");

      System.out.println(find("eggs"));
      System.out.println(find("butter"));


      public int find(String name) {
         return items.indexOf(name);
      }
```

Prints

```
2
-1
```

That method of the `List` interface pretty much negates the need to write you own method.  I just did it for demonstration purposes.

This example was using a `List of Strings` and not `ShoppingItem` class.  You could get a `List<ShoppingItem>` to work by overriding the `equals` method in your class (something you should get in the habit of anyway).

And here is a taste of how would do it with Stream (java 8+). It presumes `list` is a simple array of `ShoppingItem`.

```java
  public int find(String name) {
      return IntStream.range(0, list.length).filter(
            i -> list[i].item.equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findFirst().orElse(-1);
   }
```